# Как объединить два элемента ArrayList<String> в один элемент

Tags: java, коллекции, arraylist

Допустим, у меня есть список `ArrayList<String>`, который содержит элементы:

```
[0] <название_пары_1>
[1] <преподаватель_1>
[2] <название_пары_2>
[3] <преподаватель_2>
```

Нужно изменить список так, чтобы получилось следующее.

```
[0] <название_пары_1> <преподаватель_1>
[1] <название_пары_2> <преподаватель_2>
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите изменить именно исходный список, то используйте сложение строк и метод удаления элемента из списка `remove`, который для удобства возвращает значение удаляемого элемента

```
    // каким то образом получаем исходный список
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("C");
    list.add("D");

    // попарно суммируем элементы и удаляем ненужные, пока список не кончиться
    for (int i =0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        list.set(i, list.get(i) + list.remove(i+1));
    }

    // смотрим результат
    System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: Почему-то я ожидал, что из-за `remove` и `size` алгоритм сломается, но нет :)

Comment: list.size() выполняется в каждом цикле, т.е. значение этого поля обновляется с изменением размера списка. Если присвоить это значение переменной и проверять i<переменная - то да, сломается.

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм такой:
1. Создаёте новый список.
2. Добавляете в нулевую ячейку нового списка сумму нулевой и первой ячеек старого списка.
3. Повторяете это действие нужное число раз для следующей ячейки нового списка и каждой пары ячеек старого списка.

Answer (score 0):

Шаги:

- Создаем список
- Перебираем индексы первого списка с шагом 2
- Добавляем в новый список конкатенацию текущего и следующего за ним элемента

Код:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");
list.add("D");

List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += 2) {
    newList.add(list.get(i) + list.get(i + 1));
}

System.out.println(newList); // [AB, CD]
```